# How to add en enum to a WPF contextmenu

Tags: wpf, data-binding, c#-4.0

I have an enumeration "HelperMenu" which I want to add to a textbox in WPF.
It won't work and I don't know what I do wrong here:

enum:

```
 public enum HelperMenu
 {
    Klant,
    Eindklant,
    Email,
    Telfoonnummer,
    GSM
 }
```

XAML code:

```
 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:data="clr-namespace:RFPModule.GUI"

 <UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Menu" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="data:HelperMenu"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TextBox>
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}" />
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your `ItemsSource` binding to:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Menu}}" />
```

Your *current* binding means "bind to the `Menu` property of `this.DataContext`" whereas you want to say "bind to the resource with `Key` == Menu"